# Insert value from JSlider in to OpenCV TresholdFunction

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I'm using JSlider to change treshold values but it does work but every image is opened in new window ChangeListener is geting value from a slider but how to use it insade of Imgproc.threshold

```java
public class event implements ChangeListener {

         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
              value = slider.getValue();
              label.setText("Current Value " + value);
              converter();

         public static void main(String agrs[]){

             System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
             Draw sl = new Draw();
             sl.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             sl.setSize(300,100);
             sl.setVisible(true);
             sl.setTitle("Slider Bar");
             sl.converter();


         }

     public void converter(){


             Mat imageInMat = Imgcodecs.imread("C:/Users/ja/workspace/imgtomath/bin/imgtomath/bowl.jpg",0);
             if(imageInMat.empty()== true)
                 {System.out.println("Error no image found!!");}
             else
                 System.out.println("Image loaded");


             Mat thresh = new Mat();
            Imgproc.threshold(imageInMat, thresh, value, 250, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

            BufferedImage bufImage = Mat2BufferedImage(thresh); 
            displayImage(bufImage); 
            }
```

Comment: What does `displayImage()` do (specifically)? It sounds like it launches a new window to display the image. Can you post that code ? If you have just cut and pasted code from http://answers.opencv.org/question/8119/how-to-display-image-on-java-release/ then this line `JFrame frame=new JFrame();` is what's causing a new window for each image

Comment: Yes displayImage() will launch new window   `public void displayImage(Image img2)
 {   
 ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img2);
 JFrame frame=new JFrame();
 
 frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
 
 frame.setSize(img2.getWidth(null)+50, img2.getHeight(null)+50);     
 
 JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
 lbl.setIcon(icon); 
 frame.add(lbl);
 frame.setVisible(true);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}`